# youtube gdata api doesn't return full reports

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to fetch subscriptions of a youtube channel

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/BHUMGroup/subscriptions?v=2';
```

XML returned doesn't cover all the statistics.
For example there is a channel `http://gdata.youtube.com/apple` I am subscribed to
but it is not listed in XML

anyone knows how to fix it or any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can add query parameters to the url. With the `max-results` query you can fetch a maximum of 50 results. If you want more than 50 requests, you need to call this multiple times with `start-index` query.

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/BHUMGroup/subscriptions?v=2&max-results=50` will give maximum of 50 results. Fetch the next 50 results by adding the query `start-index=51&max-results=50`. Currently this is the only way you can achieve it.